# crystal report enterprise, create a column from two

Tags: crystal-reports

Iam working on crystal report enterprise. My data source is from an universe.
I have two columns which are only return 1 row.

```
Column A   Column B
value A    value B
```

now i want to merge it into a column like this:

```
Column C
value A
value B
```

I have searching for some crystal report formula but they don't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 sub reports inside main report.

```
1. In First sub report take `Column A` // Place in Details A
2. In second sub report take `Column b` // Place in Details B
```

Place two sub reports in 2 detail sections

Comment: Hello Siva, sorry for late reply. But my purpose for this column C is put it in an pie chart to compare so i need this column display only in single object.

Comment: I don't understand how display in report is dependent on pie chart... how rows are present in bot columns?

Comment: Hi Siva, Thanks for your reply,In my case ,I dont need to display column C, i want to create an pie chart which show percentage base on 2 column A and B, and i want bind its data to some other field do display legend in chart. Thus i need a column C for using in pie chart and make some caculate.